# With the new CoC: will links to idownvotedbecau.se be considered rude?

Tags: discussion, comments, code-of-conduct

In lieu of the ongoing discussion about [the new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review) I would like to know if linking to http://idownvotedbecau.se is considered to be *rude and toxic*.

I pledge guilty for providing comments with this link in it - mostly not "link only" comments but elaborating on the issue at hand.

I find them immensely useful, as they:

- provide lots of detail why I (and other people) might downvote this post
- provide the "ping me back if you changed your post and I revert my vote" message
- give a good approximation about the most common "beginner" errors

I found them quite helpful in my beginning and that's why I adopted the usage of them.

So my question is, is http://idownvotedbecau.se flaggable as rude or acceptable?

---

Edit:

Cerbus explained that rules of before will stick, so the link (if not posted link only) is still ok and the dupes answers hold even after CoC.

Comment: They are already very often and very successfully flagged as "no longer needed", I think.

Comment: I've had some positive response to such comments. A few users actually _did_ improve their questions.

Comment: @PatrickArtner According to Tim Post here nothing will change in the current enforcement on SO: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312850/the-second-draft-of-our-code-of-conduct-is-available-for-feedback-and-review?cb=1#comment1024785_312850

Comment: @Magisch - ok then it could be a dupe. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think the point is dumping that link in a comment isn't helpful, if that's all that the comment contains. But no, the new CoC doesn't really affect this.

Comment: ... Why is this getting re-open votes? The rules aren't changing drastically. It's still answered by the dupe target.

Comment: @Cerbrus Hmm. FWIW, I voted to reopen before reading the comments - and in particular before seeing the link to Tim's claim that the new CoC is not intended to represent a change in the rules (which is great news!). I suppose with that in mind, this really is a duplicate - but I can't retract now.

Comment: @MarkAmery: I guess we learned to _read everything_ before voting?

Comment: @Cerbrus All other votes are retractable; I usually vote before delving into the comments. This is the first time I've wanted to retract a reopen vote, and got caught out.

Comment: @MarkAmery: you can make it up by re-close-voting when it gets re-opened ;-)

Comment: @MarkAmery Edited the comments parts into the question to avoid more reopen votes ;)

Comment: I don't understand how 'dumping a link' could be seen as not helpful, (in itself, assuming the page linked contains relevant info).  Most users are familiar with hyperlinks and can follow them without any problem.